# How to edit and run the source code of an android open source native app on an emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, native, android-source, forceclose

I have successfully downloaded the source code for the AOSP Native Music Player and plan on building my own custom music player off of this basic build (I'm assuming this is legal because the code is open source). The problem I have is that even with minor code change and renaming the package, the emulator still seems to think that my app and the android Music app are the same. When I click run, eclipse installs but does not start my app. When I click Music in the app drawer it asks me which package I want to use (My package causes a force close). Does anyone know what's going wrong and how to make it so that I can run my app as a separate app? If it helps, logcat is reading "Unable to Instantiate Activity ComponentInfo on the first line of the stack trace.